# Creating Uri to virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp-classic, httpwebrequest, uri

I created a simple console application in C# to connect to a classic asp file on a web server.  I am receiving a 500 - internal server error and I think it is because I am creating the Uri using the physical path of the file and not the virtual directory path.
The web server is 2003 and using IIS 6.0

Say the physicial path is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HV1\App2\Pa3\ASP\Service.asp
The web site: HV_Site
The virtual directory is: App1
The virtual directory physical path is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HV1.

I create an Uri for the HttpWebRequest using the physical path:

```
Uri aspUri = new Uri("http://<serverName>:<port>/HV1/App2/Pa3/ASP/Service.asp?<parameters>");
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(aspPagingServiceUri);
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";               
                var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

At the response line I get a 500 error.
I believe it is because I need to incorporate the virtual directory into the request.
I tried creating the Uri like this:
`Uri aspUri = new Uri("http://<servername>:<port>/App1/App2/Pa3/ASP/Service.asp?<parameters>")`

I get a 404 error when I do that.

How do I create the Uri using a virtual directory?

Thanks.

Comment: check the error log for details about the 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to basics...I created a simple 'Hello World' asp page and put it on the web server in the directory I need to be in.  It is display.  I can also get it to display in my console application.  I will build the page from this simple page.

Thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have understood your question, but if you know the site is "HV_Site" and virtual directory is: "App1", your URI will be http://HV_Site/App1/Service.asp.
If you try that, I think it should work. 
What is "aspPagingServiceUri" here?

Comment: Instead of "aspPagingServiceUri", do you want to write "aspUri"?

Comment: Yes. It is aspUri. I cut & paste from my code. I changed the path for this post for security reasons. Thanks. I will try adding the website to the path and see if that works.

Comment: Creating the URI as http://HV Site/App/Service.asp returns a 404 error.  When I use the file path the error is a 500 error. There is an application that calls this Service.asp file and it uses the path `/App1/App2/Pa3/ASP/Service.asp?<parameters>`.  When I try to do with with my console application, I get a 404 error

Comment: When you try to access the link from a browser what happens? Does that open the page?

Comment: No.  The page does not open.  There is a HTTP 500 error.  The website cannot display this page.

Comment: I don't know if this matters but the web site is 2 words.  It is HV Site.  The virtual directory is App1.  When I put the path in a browser, get the 404 error.  This page just has a function that text messages a person.  It is not a full fledged web site.

Comment: If you are getting 404 on browser, I think the app is behaving properly. Why don't you try putting a simple page (a dummy one)? The problem might be with the page you are calling...